# What is the easiest way to determine the length of a ebook (in epub and such)?

Tags: ebook, epub

I'm interested in an way to determine the character count of the text of a ebook (epub, mobi, fb2) that is easier then converting it to plain text. A simple win32 utility or a site with drag and drop uploading would be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in an way that is easier then converting it to plain text.

What do you mean can be easier than that?

You can just convert fb2 to txt (to get rid of tags) and then do `wc -c file.txt` to count characters number.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this for PDF, (it works fine with .txt files) but what about an online tool? Such as http://felix-cat.com/tools/wordcount/

Comment: I want something similar, just for epub.

Comment: The page is 404.